# grouping indices in pyspark

Tags: sql, r, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I want to generate unique (numerical) labels to each group in my data in pyspark. Similar to group_indices in R: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_indices.html

So I looked into dense_rank() over a window. But I want the groups to be labelled in ascending order. Can I do `window.orerBy('column').partitionBy('column')` for this?
Note: **partition and order by the same column**.

Comment: maybe my question was not clear, I strictly want the groups to be labeled in ascending order. Like 'abc' --> 1, 'bcd' --> 2, 'efg' --> 3..

Comment: Simply order by is enough, I think.

Comment: yea that worked. I thought partitioning was also required.. Thanks !